# Question about "neither of"

Tags: grammar, sentence

I was going through some 5th grader's assignment and there was a question which required the synthesis of two sentences.

1. *Mary is not going to attend the party.*
2. *Jane is not going to attend the party too.*

The questions dictates that the sentence must start with "*Neither of...*". The answer provided by the teacher was: "*Neither of Mary and Jane is going to attend the workshop.*"

For some reason, this bothers me tremendously. I don't really understand why, but I know I would be less uncomfortable with: "Neither of the girls, Mary and Jane, is going to attend the workshop."

Comment: *_Jane is not going to attend the party too_ is ungrammatical. It should be _either,_ not _too_. Is this an English textbook? Is this an English-speaking country?

Answer (score 1):

You should not forget that "neither" is paired with "nor" rather than "or". I think the rule of thumb is "neither, nor and either, or"

If "neither" must be used in the sentence, I would try:

Neither Mary nor Jane will attend the workshop.

Comment: That would be my version too. The teacher's version seems very clumsy to me. 'Of' after 'neither' is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

**"Neither of Mary and Jane is going to attend the workshop."**

Basically your instincts are correct if you use the **of** then "of the girls" is needed. But to be honest it adds nothing to an already cluttered sentence.

There are three things that bother me about this sentence "**Neither**" Secondly "**of Mary and Jane**" and thirdly "**is going to attend**" Obviously the **of** should not be there. "is going" should be **will** Why use the neither format when it is more precise to say **"not"**

**Neither, Mary nor Jane will attend the workshop.**

A better sentence would be

**Mary and Jane will not attend the workshop**

Comment: I know what some comments will say! That, it is formed this way because it is an example. However if you are teaching you should take the time to find a correct sentence. If you teach a technical subject you cannot use incorrect data just because it is convenient. So why should the "Arts"